# How to make average value in onSpeechVolumeChanged react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-voice

I have i project with speech-to-text in react native, and now the problem in with speech Vloume, how to make average value from this function?

```
 const onSpeechVolumeChanged = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    setPitch(e.value);
  };
```

And the log in the console is:

```
{"value": -2}
 LOG  {"value": -0.440000057220459}
 LOG  {"value": 0.7599999904632568}
 LOG  {"value": 1.3600001335144043}
 LOG  {"value": -0.440000057220459}
 LOG  {"value": -1.7599999904632568}
 LOG  {"value": -2}
 LOG  {"value": 0.2799999713897705}
 LOG  {"value": 1}
 LOG  {"value": 2.440000057220459}
 LOG  {"value": 2.8000001907348633}
 LOG  {"value": 5.920000076293945}
```

There is a codem with makes speech to text. And y take here a NaN

```
  let [started, setStarted] = useState(false);
  let [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [voiceData, setVoiceData] = useState([])
}
  useEffect(() => {
    Voice.onSpeechError = onSpeechError;
    Voice.onSpeechResults = onSpeechResults;
    Voice.onSpeechVolumeChanged = onSpeechVolumeChanged;

    return () => {
      Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);
      
    }
  }, []);

  const startSpeechToText = async () => {
    await Voice.start("ru");
    setStarted(true);
  };

  const onSpeechVolumeChanged = (e) => {
    setVoiceData({...voiceData, volume: e.value});
  };

  const stopSpeechToText = async () => {
    await Voice.stop();
    setStarted(false);
  };

  const onSpeechResults = (result) => {
    var allValue = result.value
    var theBestOption = allValue[Object.keys(allValue).pop()]
    setResults(theBestOption)
    console.log(theBestOption)
    let sum = 0;
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < voiceData.length; i++) {
        sum += voiceData[i];
        count++;
    }
    let average = sum / count;
    console.log(average)
  };

  const onSpeechError = (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  };
```

Here takes an NuN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [voiceData, setVoiceData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    Voice.onSpeechError = onSpeechError;
    Voice.onSpeechResults = onSpeechResults;
    Voice.onSpeechVolumeChanged = onSpeechVolumeChanged;
    // added this line ->
    Voice.onSpeechStart = onSpeechStart;
    return () => {
        Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);
    }
}, []);
// added thit lines ->
const onSpeechStart = (e) => {
    // flush the data array
    voiceData.splice(0, voiceData.length);
    // if not works try this ->
    setVoiceData([]);
}
const onSpeechError = (e) => {
    console.log('onSpeechError: ', e);
}
const onSpeechResults = (e) => {
    let sum = 0;
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < voiceData.length; i++) {
        sum += voiceData[i];
        count++;
    }
    let average = sum / count;
    console.log(average)
}
const onSpeechVolumeChanged = (e) => {
    console.log('onSpeechVolumeChanged: ', e);
    voiceData.push(e.value);
}
```

Comment: When the user finishes speaking, the onSpeechEnd function will calculate the average volume for you

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Comment: const [voiceData, setVoiceData] = useState([]);

    const onSpeechVolumeChanged = (e) => {
        setVoiceData([...voiceData, e.value]);
    }
    const onSpeechEnd = (e) => {
        // get average pitch
        let sum = 0;
        let count = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < voiceData.pitches.length; i++) {
            sum += voiceData.pitches[i];
            count++;
        }
        let average = sum / count;
Try this code

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Comment: check the answer, I'm edited code

Comment: I take in the log  NaN

Comment: can u console.log(voiceData) please?

Comment: i update the qustion with code

Comment: TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method., js engine: hermes

Comment: please check if you have an array instead of an object here 
const [voiceData, setVoiceData] = useState([])

it means that the constant from which you are trying to make a loop is not iterable

Comment: the same exception and nAn

Comment: check with the console.log whether you have data recorded in state

Comment: what did you mean data recorder?

Comment: now again TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method., js engine: hermes

Comment: const onSpeechVolumeChanged = (e) => {
        voiceData.push(e.value);
    }

Comment: and how can i reset it with each launch of the recognizer

Comment: Add another event called onSpeechStart and paste this line
setVoiceData(voiceData => []);

Comment: and where i need to call it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to average a certain amount of data? For example, you can keep 10 data in an array and give the average to setPitch function